# Write about why XX is an intellectual fit for you

Tags: academic-writing

It comes to me when a graduate school application form asks me

```
why do you think XX university is an intellectual fit for you
```

How should I write about it?

Thanks

Comment: This is far too localized.  A better question would be to ask about how to write an essay (or short answer) for a graduate school in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to your other question.

You must do the homework about the university. Investigate what they are known for. Are they a leader in a particular field? Do the professors publish books which are known outside academic circles? Are the professors themselves notable? Who are some well-known alumni, and what are their contributions to their fields or industries?

Then you have to figure out what your strengths are. Are you good in languages? Philosophy? Music? Math? Science?

Match up the two. Write about it.

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to put my mind on these questions before I make my final decision.